# How to view all classified instances in WEKA API

Tags: java, classification, weka, prediction

I would like to view my classified instances.

I tried something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dataSet.size(); i++) {
    double pred = nowy.classifyInstance(dataSet.instance(i));
    double actual = dataSet.instance(i).classValue();
    double[] dist = nowy.distributionForInstance(dataSet.instance(i));

    if (pred != actual)
    {
        System.out.print((i+1));
        System.out.print(" - ");
        System.out.print(dataSet.instance(i).toString(dataSet.classIndex()));
        System.out.print(" - ");
        System.out.print(dataSet.classAttribute().value((int) pred));
        System.out.print(" - ");

        if (pred != dataSet.instance(i).classValue())
            System.out.print("no");
        else
            System.out.print("yes");
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

but it seems that it does not work well because the number of correctly/incorrectly classified instances are different from the statistics output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also test all instances in one go by using the Evaluation class provided in the WEKA API.

```
Instances trainData = ds.getDataset(); //get training dataset

SMO sm = new SMO(); //build classifier

sm.buildClassifier(data); //train classifier

Instances testData = ds.getDataSet(); //now get the test set

Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(data); //for recording results

eval.evaluateModel(sm, testData);

System.out.println(eval.toMatrixString()); //gives the confusion matrix for predictions
```